# Remove time between audio files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have an HTML5 `<audio>` element that I change the src to every minute with the following code:

```
$(Audio)[0].src = newBlobURL;
$(Audio)[0].load();
$(Audio)[0].play();
```

There is a brief stop between the previous audio and the next audio. Both audio files are in wav format and are stored in Blob URLs.

How can I remove the stop between audio files? This problem can be heard more on i-OS safari but it can be reproduced on most browsers.

Comment: every second is too short I think here... plus you better preload them all at once then loop through the sources..

Comment: Sorry, it is actually every minute.

Answer (score 2):

The delay is likely from loading the new audio file. Try loading all of your audio at once when the page is loaded. Then you can play them one at a time without loading each one in real time.

Run all of the source and load all at once when the page loads.

```
$(Audio)[0].src = newBlobURL;
$(Audio)[0].load();
```

Comment: How should I load them? They are already preloaded with blob URLs.

Comment: Try checking the "network" tab or your browser's developer tools. From there you will be able to see when it is making the requests, whether everything is being loaded all at once.

Comment: everything is loaded at once

Comment: Please post the full code that deals with the audio.

Comment: the audio is loaded with createobjecturl and stored in the newbloburl variable.